# makefile and command line in terminal

Tags: makefile, terminal

I have a command line which could run in terminal :

```
nwave nand_sim.fsdb -play hello.tcl
```

But when I add this line in my makefile, I got:

nwave command not found

Why is that? Isn`t comand in terminal and command in makefile execute the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Finding a command is done by searching your PATH environment variable.  The setting for this isn't the same in the shell and in a makefile.  Its best to always include the whole path to a command, especially when its not in a standard directory.

Comment: It`s really odd.I have another command 'ncverilog' which is also a third-party software I installed, which executed perfectly in both makefile and terminal. how can I get the whole path of the command 'nwave' in my system? And how should I include it in the makefile? Thanks

Comment: I've never seen the behaviour you describe; PATH is inherited by `make`, unless, perhaps, the `makefile` itself sets PATH.

Comment: I find 'nwave' is a user defined command in .bashrc using 'alias'.   It works after I change it to the the right command.